# What is the meaning of "fairly", "no going" and "going in" in this context?

Tags: meaning

> The tunnel wound on and on, going **fairly** but not quite straight
>   into the side of the hill - The Hill, as all the people for many miles
>   round called it – and many little round doors opened out of it, first
>   on one side and then on another. **No going** upstairs for the hobbit:
>   bedrooms, bathrooms, cellars, pantries (lots of these), wardrobes (he
>   had whole rooms devoted to clothes), kitchens, dining-rooms, all were
>   on the same floor, and indeed on the same passage. The best rooms were
>   all on the left-hand side (**going in**), for these were the only ones
>   to have windows, deep-set round windows looking over his garden and
>   meadows beyond, sloping down to the river.

This context is from "The Hobbit" and i've never seen these words in a context like this. "Fairly" means "to some extent", but I can't undertand that with the verb "to go". The same happens with "no going" and "going in". I believe this does not mean "to go somewhere". Does they mean there were no stairs (for the first) and the side from we go into the hole (for the second)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Fairly** modifies *straight*, with the meaning of *to some extent* or *almost* straight. Therefore, the sense of it is that the tunnel follows a path into the hillside that is almost straight, or slighltly curved or crooked.

**No going** means that it is not necessary or even possible to use stairs to go from one part of the dwelling to another, since there were none. All the rooms and passageways are on the same level.To write the phrase more fully, it might be, "There was no going upstairs for the Hobbit."

On the left side **going in**, means that as one enters the house and proceeds down the hallway, the rooms with windows are all on the left side of the hall.